# no auth token for request W/StorageUtil(12124): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: No AppCheckProvider installed

Tags: flutter, firebase

[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpL9A.png) I am making simple flutter project to upload image file on firebase, I have done all the codes and it seems there is not any error integrating firebase into my flutter app because app does not crashes. I can select image  but when I click upload button i get this error:
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
E/StorageException(12124):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
E/StorageException(12124):  ... 5 more

Here is my code of two buttons:

```html
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:imageupload/storage_service.dart';

class ImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageUpload({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageUpload> createState() => _ImageUploadState();
}

class _ImageUploadState extends State<ImageUpload> {
  UploadTask? task;
  File? imageFile;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Storage storage = Storage();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Image Upload Demo"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        // decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text("Select image"),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 150,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          selectFile();
                        },
                        child: Text("selact Image"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 150,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            uploadFile();
                            // pickImage();
                          },
                          child: Text("Upload Image")),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ]),
            ),
            // imageFile != null
            //     ? Container(
            //         height: 300, width: 200, child: Image.file(imageFile!))
            //     : Text("No Image selected"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);
    if (result == null) return;
    final path = result.files.single.path!;
    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(path);
    });

    print("Files selected");
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    final fileName = imageFile!.path;
    final destination = 'images/$fileName';
    Storage.uploadFile(destination, imageFile!);
    print("Files selected");
  }
}
```

Here is the code to upload the image to firebase:

```html
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;

class Storage {
  static UploadTask? uploadFile(String destination, File file) {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);

      return ref.putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  
}
```

I have not enabled appCheck features from firebase, and i have given permission to all user in the firebase project by doing:

```html
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried making another firebase project and connected to my flutter project but i still am getting same error, I don't see exact answers and I have tried many other method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
 }
```